# How to set record rules in odoo?

Tags: odoo

How to create rule to display only subordinates leave records in odoo

Example, XXX is Manager of A,B,C, Employees YYY is Manager of X,Y,Z, Employees

XXX and YYY Has related users with Access Rights Officer/Manager

If XXX logs in then, He can Approve Leave Request, Approve Timesheet of X,Y,Z employees also, how to restrict this...?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
['|',(user_id,'=',user.id),('manager_id.user_id','=',user.id)]
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer but i am getting these error.ValueError: "name 'user_id' is not defined" while evaluating
u"['|',(user_id,'=',user.id),('manager_id.user_id','=',user.id)]"

Comment: If user_id is a field on your model, use quotes like this 'user_id'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
['|',('employee_id.user_id','=',user.id),('department_id.manager_id.user_id','=',user.id)]
```

it does work for me in expense approval.